# what is the best way to parse out string from longer string?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

i have a string that looks like this:

```
"/dir/location/test-load-ABCD.p"
```

and i need to parse out "ABCD" (where ABCD will be a different value every day)

The only things that i know that will always be consistent (to use for the logic for parsing) are:

1. There will always be be a ".p" after the value
2. There will always be a "test-load-" before the value.

The things i thought of was somehow grab everything past the last "/" and then remove the last 2 characters (to take case of the ".p" and then to do a

```
 .Replace("test-load-", "")
```

but it felt kind of hacky so i wanted to see if people had any suggestions on a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
static readonly Regex parser = new Regex(@"/test-load-(.+)\.p");

string part = parser.Match(str).Groups[1].Value;
```

For added resilience, replace `.+` with a character class containing only the characters that can appear in that part.

**Bonus**:
You probably next want

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(part, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a file name, use the file name parsing facility offered by the framework:

```
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("/dir/location/test-load-ABCD.p");
string result = fileName.Replace("test-load-", "");
```

A “less hacky” solution than using `Replace` would be the use of regular expressions to capture the solution but I think this would be overkill in this case.

Comment: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - does FileInfo actually check that this is a real file that exists as this above don't actually map onto real files

Comment: @ooo No, it doesn’t. Otherwise you couldn’t work with files that don’t yet exist, which would be a major limitation.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "/dir/location/test-load-ABCD.p";

Regex.Match(input, @"test-load-([a-zA-Z]+)\.p$").Groups[1].Value
```